# Find the minimum positive-integer value which meets the requirement

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

If the equation is

```
Mod[515 Sum[10^(3 d), {d, 0, n}], 53] == 0
```

then I can get the minimum positive-integer value of `n` with

```
minint[x_, y_] := 
 Module[{len = IntegerLength[x], n = 1}, 
  While[! Divisible[x (Sum[10^(len d), {d, 0, n}]), y], n++]; n + 1]

minint[515, 53]
```

> 13

But if the equation is

```
Mod[305745211 Sum[10^(9 d), {d, 0, n}], 182593] == 0
```

the `minint` needs a long long time to run. I want to get a most high-efficiency method to do it. Help please.

PS:

> The answer is $20288$ as I know.

Comment: surely `Mod[305745211 Sum[10^(6 d), {d, 0, n}], 182593] == 0` should be `Mod[305745211 Sum[10^(9 d), {d, 0, n}], 182593] == 0` because `305745211` has 9 digits, not 6

Comment: Thanks for your point out,It is a typo.And I have corrected it.

Comment: Then the simple code in my answer is correct, and fast enough :)

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G I'm studying what you have write.And thanks for your concern about this :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to repeat all the summing in each step, just keep a running tally and add an appropriately updated increment.

```
m = 182593;
mult = Mod[10^6, m];
n1 = Mod[305745211, m];
next = n1;
val = n1;
j = 0;
AbsoluteTiming[
 While[j <= 10^6 && Mod[val, m] != 0, j++; next = Mod[mult*next, m]; 
  val += next]; j]

(* Out[1461]= {0.059061, 30431} *)
```

Comment: +1 You could start just with `val = next = 1;` No need for `n1`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I haven't had enough coffee yet.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/0ZDf13W

Comment: @Dr.belisarius If you have seen China's Spring Festival gala,more strange way to brewed it will turn up.

Comment: Is there a slip in current code?

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing the notation of @BobHanlon, the analytic solution to the sum is $x*Sum[10^{c*d},\{d,0,n\}]=x*(10^{c*(n+1)}-1)/(10^c-1)$.

Mod $m$, the equation may be written as follows

```
Mod[x,m] * (PowerMod[10, c*(n+1), m]-1) * PowerMod[PowerMod[10, c, m]-1, -1, m]
```

which takes advantage of the fast `PowerMod` mentioned by @DanielLichtblau.

Note that substituting values for $x$, $c$, and $m$ gives an equation like

```
z * (PowerMod[10,c*(n+1),m] - 1) = 0,
```

where $z$ is a positive integer. Hence, the problem simplifies to finding a solution for `PowerMod[10,c*(n+1),m]=1`.

`MultiplicativeOrder[10,m]` gives the smallest integer $k$ such that $10^k=1$, mod $m$. The smallest positive integer multiple of $k$, say $i*k$, giving an integer solution for $n$ in $i*k=c*(n+1)$ solves the problem with $n=i*k/c-1$.

For example, $x=515$, $c=3$, and $m=53$ requires `PowerMod[10,3*(n+1),53]=1`. In this case, `MultiplicativeOrder[10,53]=13`, and $n=i*13/3-1$. The smallest integer $n=12$ results for $i=3$.

The large example gives `PowerMod[10,6*(n+1),182593]=1`, and `MultiplicativeOrder[10,182593]=182592`. Thus, $n=i*182592/6-1=30431$ when $i=1$.

The only calculation required is `MultiplicativeOrder[10,m]`, which takes zero time. `MultiplicativeOrder` is undefined when `GCD[10,m]>1`, but the two moduli given in the question were both prime.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f, minint]
```

Perform the `Sum` analytically.

```
f[x_, n_, c_] = x Sum[10^(c* d), {d, 0, n}];

minint[x_, y_, c_] := Module[{n = 1}, While[Mod[f[x, n, c], y] != 0, n++]; n]
```

Note that `minint` should return `n` vice `n+1`.

```
minint[515, 53, 3] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.000105, 12}  *)
```

Verification that `12` is the correct value

```
Mod[515 Sum[10^(3 d), {d, 0, 12}], 53] == 0

(*  True  *)

minint[305745211, 182593, 6] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {12.5941, 30431}  *)
```

Verification

```
Mod[305745211 Sum[10^(6 d), {d, 0, 30431}], 182593] == 0

(*  True  *)
```

I do not know if `13 seconds` meets your efficiency requirement

Comment: This would probably be quite fast with judicious use of `PowerMod` to avoid computing those large powers of 10 in `f[x,n,c]`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure OP made a mistake in describing the problem. The problem is finding a zero mod of a large number made by repeating digits.

```
minint[x_, y_] := Block[
  {lenX = IntegerLength[x], r = x, m = 1, n = 1},
  While[! Divisible[r, y], m = 10^lenX*m; r = m*x + r; n++];
  {n, r}
  ]
```

lets test with first correct example

```
minint[515,53]
(* {13, 515515515515515515515515515515515515515} *)
```

now lets test with second example that OP somewhat bungled the description

```
minint[305745211, 182593]
(* {20288,305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211305745211... *)
```

The integer is quite long indeed! (cut off for sanity)